# How to add a list of datetime?

Tags: python, list, datetime, time, sum

```
['00:00:36', '00:02:54', '00:06:06', '00:07:28', '00:07:57', '00:10:44', '00:11:34', '00:14:57', '00:15:03', '00:17:01', '00:17:13', '00:18:28', '00:18:50', '00:23:41', '00:25:47']
```

1) I have a datetime.datetimeobject (basically time stamp) but I just pulled out HH:MM:SS and printed it here. How can I add this(datetime.datetime object)?

```
[{'Start Time': '2017-01-01 00:00:36'}, {'Start Time': '2017-01-01 00:02:54'}, {'Start Time': '2017-01-01 00:06:06'}, {'Start Time': '2017-01-01 00:07:28'}, {'Start Time': '2017-01-01 00:07:57'}, {'Start Time': '2017-01-01 00:10:44'}, {'Start Time': '2017-01-01 00:11:34'}, {'Start Time': '2017-01-01 00:14:57'}, {'Start Time': '2017-01-01 00:15:03'}, {'Start Time': '2017-01-01 00:17:01'}, {'Start Time': '2017-01-01 00:17:13'}, {'Start Time': '2017-01-01 00:18:28'}, {'Start Time': '2017-01-01 00:18:50'}, {'Start Time': '2017-01-01 00:23:41'}, {'Start Time': '2017-01-01 00:25:47'}]
```

2) Should I convert it all to seconds add them out and return to time or is there a better and neat way to do this? 
3) '00:00:36' this value becomes a string right?

#### output (1) should be in HH:MM:SS format.

#### output (2) DD:HH:MM:SS format.

Comment: Do you have a list of `datetime.datetime` objects, or a list of strings? Your question title implies the former, but your code sample data implies for latter.

Comment: @Robᵩ The list is shown on the first line but none of them seem to have date information.

Comment: datetime.datetime objects (basically timestamp) but I just pulled out HH:MM:SS

Comment: @ChrisD'mello But you just want to add them together right? How do dates factor in to this question? What is the proper end result to this list?

Comment: end result could be in seconds or DD:HH:MM:SS or HH:MM:SS

Comment: @ChrisD'mello Isn't that what my answer already does?

Answer (score 0):

That would depend on what you want to do with the values.  For maximum flexibility,  you could store an array of datetime.time objects and use formatting for the type of output you want to see using time.strftime()

Answer (score 0):

```
DD_HH_MM_SS = '{:0>2}:{:0>2}:{:0>2}:{:0>2}'
HH_MM_SS = '{:0>2}:{:0>2}:{:0>2}'


def from_seconds(seconds):
    days, seconds = divmod(seconds, 86400)
    hours, seconds = divmod(seconds, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
    return days, hours, minutes, seconds


def to_seconds(hhmmss):
    hours, minutes, seconds = (int(a) for a in hhmmss.split(':'))
    return (hours * 3600) + (minutes * 60) + seconds


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dates = [
        '00:00:36',
        '00:02:54',
        '00:06:06',
        '00:07:28',
        '00:07:57',
        '00:10:44',
        '00:11:34',
        '00:14:57',
        '00:15:03',
        '00:17:01',
        '00:17:13',
        '00:18:28',
        '00:18:50',
        '00:23:41',
        '00:25:47'
    ]
    total_seconds = sum(to_seconds(date) for date in dates)
    days, hours, minutes, seconds = from_seconds(total_seconds)

    print(HH_MM_SS.format((days * 24) + hours, minutes, seconds))
    print(DD_HH_MM_SS.format(days, hours, minutes, seconds))
```

Console:

```
03:18:19
00:03:18:19
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the time strings to total number of seconds and then sum up the values to get a total time (in seconds).  Then break that down into days, hours, minutes and seconds:

```
data       = ['00:00:36', '00:02:54', '00:06:06', '00:07:28', '00:07:57', '00:10:44', '00:11:34', '00:14:57', '00:15:03', '00:17:01', '00:17:13', '00:18:28', '00:18:50', '00:23:41', '00:25:47']
components = [ [int(c) for c in time.split(":")] for time in data ]
totalTime  = sum([ c[0]*3600+c[1]*60+c[2] for c in components ])
output1    = "{:2d}:{:2d}:{:2d}".format(totalTime//3600, (totalTime%3600)//60, totaltime%60)
output2    = "{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}".format(totalTime//86400,(totalTime//3600)%24, (totalTime%3600)//60, totalTime%60)

# output1 will contain '03:18:19'
# output2 will contain '00:03:18:19'
```

Comment: @Delirious Lettuce.  I had the page opened to type my answer for a while and didn't refresh before posting so I didn't see my answer was essentially the same as yours.